# Couldn't find User with id=UserNameHere when clicking followers/following

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I am trying to implement Michael Hartl's follow feature into my application, so I've had to make some little changes as I've gone along.

Problem is when I click the followers/following button. I get the error

[image: error message]

```
Here is my UsersController

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
  end

  def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:avatar)
  end


  def following
      @title = "Following"
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @users = @user.followed_users.paginate(page: params[:page])
      render 'show_follow'
    end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
  render 'show_follow'
  end 
end
```

If you need more information to get help me solve this problem, do not hesitate to let me know.

Comment: username expects a string you are giving it the id which is an int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are passing the `name` of the user instead of the `id`, you should use:

`User.find_by(name: "user_name")`